# Javascript popup only showing the last result in PHP query

Tags: javascript, php, mysql, while-loop

I have the following block of code and I'm not sure how to do what I'm wanting to do.

In essence I'm wanting the javascript popup to display that row's value, but (obviously) it's only showing the final row of data as the popup isn't set for each row but rather calls the variable when clicked.

Any help would be appreciated!

```
<?php
$result = mysql_query("SELECT hr_overtime.overtime_id, hr_user.name, hr_overtime.overtime_date, hr_overtime.overtime_type, hr_overtime.overtime_from, hr_overtime.overtime_to, hr_overtime.overtime_amount, hr_overtime.details
FROM hr_overtime 
inner join hr_user
on hr_user.user_id = hr_overtime.user_id
where hr_overtime.overtime_status = 'Pending' order by hr_overtime.overtime_date ASC");
echo "
<table border='0'>
<tr>
<th class='tablecell_header'>Consultant</th>
<th class='tablecell_header'>Date</th>
<th class='tablecell_header'>Type</th>
<th class='tablecell_header'>From</th>
<th class='tablecell_header'>To</th>
<th class='tablecell_header'>Amount</th>
<th> </th>
<th> </th>
<th> </th>
</tr>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_array($result))
  {
  $work = $row['details'];
  echo "<tr>";
    echo "<td class='tablecell'>" . $row['name'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tablecell'>" . $row['overtime_date'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tablecell'>" . $row['overtime_type'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tablecell'>" . $row['overtime_from'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tablecell'>" . $row['overtime_to'] . "</td>";
    echo "<td class='tablecell'>" . $row['overtime_amount'] . "</td>";?>
    <td class='tablecell'> <button onclick="myFunction()">Show work</button>         </td><script>
function myFunction()
{
alert("<?php echo $work;?>");
}
</script>
        <?php
    echo "<td valign='middle'><form action='manager_overtime_approve.php'     method='post'>
<input name='approve_id' type='hidden' value='" . $row['overtime_id'] . "' />
<input type='submit' value='APPROVE' id='edit' />
</form></td>";
    echo "<td valign='middle'><form action='manager_overtime_reject.php' method='post'>
<input name='cancel_id' type='hidden' value='" . $row['overtime_id'] . "' />
<input type='submit' value='REJECT' id='edit' />
</form></td>";
 echo "</tr>";
  } 
    echo "</table>";
?>
```

Comment: Warning, This extension is deprecated as of PHP 5.5.0, and will be removed in the future. [mysql_query](http://php.net/manual/es/function.mysql-query.php)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no need for a separate function which you are using incorrectly. You can simply use an inline alert for this:

```
<td class='tablecell'> <button onclick="alert('<?php echo $work;?>');">Show work</button>
```

Comment: What difference does this make?

Comment: There is no need for a separate function. An inline alert will work.

Comment: You are right, but my question was to motivate you to explain your solution more. This is one good solution and you have to put some more words there for the OP to know the usability of this approach

Comment: That makes so much sense and is so obvious now I've seen it written down... >_<

Answer (score 1):

You can't insert the declaration of `myFunction()` inside your foreach loop, that way you are overriding for each entry the behaviour showed thus it's only working for the last row.

one fast solution would be to insert the whole $work variable as an argument of your onclick function eg.

```
<td class='tablecell'> <button onclick="myFunction('<?php echo $work ?>')">Show work</button>
```

and then outside of the foreach loop you can define `myFunction` such as:

```
function myFunction(details){
  alert(details)
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I think, in result HTML you have a multiple definitions of myFunction() and javascript uses only last one. You can use a HTML tag attributes to show right information.

Answer (score 0):

try this

```
$work .= $row['details'];
```

and set javascript out of the loop
good luck

Answer (score 0):

That's because `myFunction` is a *Javascript* function, which is defined *once* and doesn *not* share the same scope as PHP. So `$work` hold just the last value.

I'd suggest something like this:

```
echo "<tr data-detail-value='$work'>";
...
<td class='tablecell'> <button onclick="myFunction(this)">Show work</button>
...
function myFunction(btn) {
   alert(btn.parentNode.parentNode.getAttribute("data-detail-value"));
}
```